# Assigning class function via constructor parameter

Tags: c++

I'm solving the 11th day of the Advent of Code.

The input is:

```
Monkey 0:
    Starting items : 79, 98
    Operation : new = old * 19
    Test : divisible by 23
    If true : throw to monkey 2
    If false : throw to monkey 3

Monkey 1 :
    Starting items : 54, 65, 75, 74
    Operation : new = old + 6
    Test : divisible by 19
    If true : throw to monkey 2
    If false : throw to monkey 0

    Monkey 2 :
    Starting items : 79, 60, 97
    Operation : new = old * old
    Test : divisible by 13
    If true : throw to monkey 1
    If false : throw to monkey 3

    Monkey 3 :
    Starting items : 74
    Operation : new = old + 3
    Test : divisible by 17
    If true : throw to monkey 0
    If false : throw to monkey 1
```

I was thinking that I could make a class which would then be used for each monkey that would kinda look like this:

```
class Monkey{
    int *Items;
    int operation();
    void throw();
}
```

The problem is that each monkey has diffent operation and throw function.

Can I somehow set this function when creating each monkey?

Comment: I think what you're looking for are [virtual functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/).

Comment: I would create an abstract base class for operations, extended by four concrete classes that implement the operations. Each monkey will get an instance of the appropriate operation class and will delegate the computation to it.

Comment: Recommendation, if allowable by the assignment, replace `int *Items;` and supporting code with `std::vector<int> items;`. `vector` will manage many of the thorny problems like sizing, counting the contents and proper destruction for you.

Comment: also, you can't name a function "throw" since it's reserved keyword.

Comment: Alternatively, observe that they do *not* have different operation and throw functions. They all have ~the same function, with different parameters.

Comment: `std::function<int(int)>` may also help